# Using SQL Server PDW in Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have Visual Studio 2013 professional and have connected to my PDW database in that. Its just my 2nd week in SQL Server PDW and I'm still trying to get accustomed to this. I don't see intellisense when writing queries. Is that a known issue or am I missing some setting here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything. There is no Intellisense for PDW yet. I would suggest voting for Redgate to support PDW for their SQL Prompt here:  https://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/94413-sql-prompt/suggestions/6013601-support-for-pdw-parallel-data-warehouse-aka-aps